# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I have the below code that use to work until I had to change my password.

Now I'm getting an error. The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

Would anyone know what my problem is and can help me solve the problem?

I'm new to coding so take it easy on me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace DevilishDetailing
{
    public partial class Contactus : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";  
        static int portNumber = 587;  
        static bool enableSSL = true;
        static string emailFromAddress = "wickedcleandetailing563@gmail.com"; // "cbrannam1@gmail.com"; //Sender Email Address  
        static string password = "*********";//"********"; //Sender Password  

        static string emailToAddress = "wickedcleandetailing563@gmail.com"; //Receiver Email Address  
        static string subject = "";  
        static string body = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            body = "From: " + txtemail.Text + "<br/>" +  txtmessage.Text;
            subject = txtname.Text;
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFromAddress);
                mail.To.Add(emailToAddress);
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                    smtp.Host = smtpAddress;
                    smtp.Port = portNumber;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFromAddress, password);                  
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should pass the password using `System.Security.SecureString` class rather than normal string.

Comment: try an apps password

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [revoke the permission of the app](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en#:~:text=Remove%20third%2Dparty%20account%20access) from the account and reauthenticate once more to refresh the token use by the app?